# How to get network, memory and CPU status on Bionic GNOME panel (system menu)?

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell

I miss the old [system monitor applet](https://itsfoss.com/best-indicator-applets-ubuntu/system-load-monitor-best-indicator-applets/), which allowed me, at a glance, to see network activity, memory status and CPU activity.

[image: System Monitor applet]

How do I get something like this back on Bionic Beaver (GNOME on Wayland) ?

Comment: I read that it Indicator Sysmonitor **does** work in 18.04 but it requires an extension to be installed. Unfortunately I haven't tried it myself yet.